# arabic,persian character encoding in laravel blade compile

Tags: php, laravel-blade

i am using laravel blade in my own mvc framework ( https://github.com/PhiloNL/Laravel-Blade ) , after blade compile process , persian and arabic characters compiled as ???? sign and i can just use english in my blade ! how can i set utf 8 in laravel blade compile for persian language ?
blade example

```
{{ "سلام" }}
```

after compile

```
<?php echo e('????'); ?>
```

Comment: Are you sure you saved the file with correct encoding?

Comment: blade file is utf-8 , it is happening after compiling blade to php file cache !

Comment: it is only happening on xamp with window ! but it is working in ubuntu lamp fine !

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problem with utf8 characters. The solution seems to be in your view blade e.g. index.blade.php not using {{$varname->dbcolumn}} but rather straightforward <?php echo htmlentities($varname->dbcolumn,ENT_QUOTES,'UTF-8'); ?> It is strange but it helpd me on Laravel 5 as you can see on the following pics https://imagebin.ca/v/3hwRrNsuFAZX  https://imagebin.ca/v/3hwSIrLWqIvr Cheers, hope it helped.